# Embedding "com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml" file into epub

Tags: epub, ibooks

I want to add the `com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml` file which is described in the ibooks documentation for publishers.

I am using sigil to create my books but i can't add this file within my epub book file.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have been able to work out, you can not add it with Sigil. Even once it is in Sigil, you can not see the contents of the file; you are only able to see the file is there. Take a look at some of the example projects [in this post](http://authoradventures.blogspot.jp/2012/01/how-to-create-fixed-layout-ibooks-part_24.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open the epub file with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), then add the **com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml**. That should do it, it did work for me.